# Como pasar un dato de un componente a otro ionic/angular

Tags: angular, ionic

soy nuevo en este tema de ionic/angular, agradecería su ayuda.
Tengo 2 componentes un Login y un Bienvenido.
En el login tengo un formulario muy simple(login.page.html)

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" value="" #username></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" value="" #password></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <div padding>
    <ion-button (click)="bienvenido()" expand="block">INICIAR SESION</ion-button>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

[image: Imagen del formulario]

El login responde a 2 usuarios creados manualmente a través de una condicional "if" en login.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  // rescato desde html el input #username
  @ViewChild('username') user;
  // rescato desde html el input #password
  @ViewChild('password') password;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  bienvenido() {
    if (this.user.value == "javier" && this.password.value == "54321") {
      this.router.navigate(['../bienvenido']);
    }
    if (this.user.value == "david" && this.password.value == "12345") {
      this.router.navigate(['../bienvenido']);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

los input los rescato del html a través de ViewChild. En este caso el login responde a los usuario "david:12345" y "javier:54321".
Al momento de ingresar uno de los 2 usuarios correctamente y presionar el botón "INICIAR SESION", el usuario será dirigido al componente bienvenido.
La idea seria que en el html bienvenido(bienvenido.page.html) se muestre el nombre del usuario, de tal manera “Bienvenido [nombre_usuario]”

[image: Imagen pagina bienvenida]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar storage, que lo que hace es mandar el nombre del usuario a el storage que es donde se almacenan los datos `storage.set()`, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```js
bienvenido() {
    if (this.user.value == "javier" && this.password.value == "54321") {
      this.storage.set('nombre_usuario', 'javier');
      this.router.navigate(['../bienvenido']);
    }
    if (this.user.value == "david" && this.password.value == "12345") {
      this.storage.set('nombre_usuario', 'david');
      this.router.navigate(['../bienvenido']);
    }
  }
```

En tu función bienvenido envías al storage el nombre del usuario que se logueo. Y para mostrarlo en tu `html` puedes crear una función que recupere el nombre del usuario logueado `storage.get()`:

```js
  nombreUsuario;
  getNombreUsuario() {
    this.nombreUsuario = this.storage.get('nombre_usuario');
  }
```

Y en el `html`

```html
<h1>BIENVENIDO {{nombreUsuario}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo: por url, servicios, localStorage, etc.

Una de las mejores es utilizar un servicio que consuman ambos componentes